# Save String (Cookie) to SharedPrefs caused NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, cookies, nullpointerexception, android-sharedpreferences

I´ve made a class with helps me to handle the Authentication (save Cookie to SharedPrefs).

```
public class Authentication extends Application {

    String PREFS_NAME = "UserData";
    String DEFAULT = "";

    Context context;
    public static SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    public static SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    public static String token;

    public Authentication(Activity context) {
        this.context = context;
        sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        token = sharedPreferences.getString("Cookie", DEFAULT);
    }

    //speichert Token in den Shared Preferences
    public static void setToken(String token) {
        Log.d("Cookie", token);
        editor.putString("Cookie", token);
        }
}
```

When I call the `Authentication.setToken(token)`-method my response (RegisterActivity) I´ll get a NullPointerException:

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.content.SharedPreferences$Editor android.content.SharedPreferences$Editor.putString(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference`

Can someone of you help me to solve this prob? Thanks in advance

Comment: Remove static keyword from method `setToken` and try

Comment: I guess you are calling `setToken()` without calling `Authentication()`before...so your `editor` is not initialized

Comment: @SagarThakarar removing the static doesn´t solve the prob...

Comment: @Yvette The `String token` comes from my HTTP-Response in the RegisterActivity!

Answer (score 2):

you are not  register your application in manifiest that. 
or first createonject of **Authentication** with your code
first register it in manifiest

change your **Authentication** with

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.util.Log;

public class Authentication extends Application {
    String PREFS_NAME = "UserData";
    String DEFAULT = "";
    Context context;
    public static SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    public static SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    public static String token;

    public Authentication() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        context  = this;
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        token = sharedPreferences.getString("Cookie", DEFAULT);
    }

    // speichert Token in den Shared Preferences
    public static void setToken(String token) {
        Log.d("Cookie", token);
        if(editor==null){
            throw new NullPointerException("Register your application "+Authentication.class+" in AndroidManifiest.xml");
        }
        editor.putString("Cookie", token);
    }

}
```

**AndroidManifiest.xml**

```
<application
        android:name="com.android.Authentication"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_home"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.blue"
         >
.
.
.
 <activity.../>
<service.../>

  </application>
```

Comment: ok... this way throws no NullPointerException, but my token is not saved in the SharedPrefs... any suggestion?

Comment: ah... Nevermind! You´ve forgot to call `editor.apply()`! Now it works perfectly, thank you :)